# Django ORM query duplicates annotated values

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have two almost equal test query:

```
test1 = (
Invoice.objects
    .filter(id=2787)
    .annotate(plan_total=Sum(
        'item_reason__planned_bank_operations__amount')
    ))

test2 = (
Invoice.objects
    .filter(id=2787)
    .annotate(
        plan_total=Sum(
            'item_reason__planned_bank_operations__amount'),
        pieces_total=Sum(
            'invoice_pieces__amount')
    ))
```

The result of `test1.values('plan_total')` returns `<QuerySet [{'plan_total': Decimal('658.00')}]>`, but when I try to get the same values of `test2.values('plan_total')` it returns `<QuerySet [{'plan_total': Decimal('1316.00')}]>`.
How could this happen?

A little bit more information about the fields above:

`item_reason` is `ForeignKey` when `planned_bank_operations` is related query which was associated by related_name in `PlanOperation` model.

Same history with `invoice_pieces`. `InvoicePiece` is individual model that have ForeignKey to Invoice with related name `InvoicePieces`.

So, I can't understand this behavior. This is a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i found the note of  the article https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by I suggested that problem is in generated SQL with GROUP_BY.

I solved this problem with a subquery:

```
test2_subquery = (
InvoiceAmountInProject.objects
    .filter(base_invoice__id=OuterRef('id'))
    .values('base_invoice__id')
    .annotate(total=Sum('amount'))
    .values('total'))

test2 = (
Invoice.objects
    .filter(id=2787)
    .annotate(
        plan_total=Sum('item_reason__planned_bank_operations__amount'),
        pieces_total=Subquery(test2_subquery)
    ))
```

Now `test2.values('plan_total')` returns right value.